# Automatic unlock bitlocker to go (usb stick) on domain computer

Tags: windows, security, windows-8.1, bitlocker

Is there a way to automatically unlock bitlocker encrypted USB sticks on windows computers that are domain joined (8.1 Enterprise)? (e.g., based on the "BitLocker identification Field"?)

The scenario I'm thinking of is that the IT department encrypts the sticks, hands them out to the user without telling the password, the user plugs them in their domain computer, key is unlocked automatically and user can work with it.

We are aware that the user cannot work with this USB stick in another (non-our-domain joined) computer, but that is actually the goal...

Answer (score 0):

Use automatic unlock with the key assigned to a user/group in Active Directory?

In the Bitlocker FAQ, section [What is Bitlocker? How does it work?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831507.aspx#BKMK_WhatIsBitLocker)

- **Active Directory Account or Group.** A key can be assigned to an Active
  Directory user, group, or computer account and when those credentials
  are presented the drive will be unlocked. Using this key protector
  requires using manage-mde or the Windows PowerShell cmdlets for
  BitLocker to manually add the ADAccountorGroup key protector. For
  more information on the cmdlet, see Add-BitLockerKeyProtector. For
  more information on the command-line syntax, see Manage-bde:
  protectors.